# Maximize product of two sines given sum of angles

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, proof-writing, triangles, angle

Say we have an angle $c$. Prove that for two angles $a$ and $b$ such that $a + b = c$,$$\sin{a}\sin{b}$$ is maximized when
$$a = b = \frac{c}{2}$$

Comment: $\sin a \cdot \sin (c-a)= \sin^2 \frac{c}2-\sin^2\left(a-\frac{c}2\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Use the trigonometric sum-product relation:

$2\sin(a)\sin(b)=\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b).$

Continue from there.